# how to Control Scrolling on the behalf of highlights Effect using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I Want to know how to Scroll up and down on the behalf of div highlights, 
Here the example : [image]

This is my Screen of **kot Entry** page when i click on item one by one that is added in left side of the image in kotEntry Section and scroll down automatically in footer but my question is when i repeated any item like **AFGANI MOMOS** (highlight that div block) still scroll stand down in footer then how to scrolling show on front of highlight div

CODE

```
     if (i.length > 0) {   // this is check for repeated item
                    debugger;
                    var s = this.cart.indexOf(i[0]);
                    var b = this.cart[s][this.options.paramSettings.productQuantity];
                    var cd = this.cart[s][this.options.paramSettings.Modifier];
                    this.cart[s][this.options.paramSettings.productQuantity] = this.cart[s][this.options.paramSettings.productQuantity] - 0 + (e[this.options.paramSettings.productQuantity] - 0), e = this.cart[s], this._triggerEvent("itemUpdated", [e]);
                } 
else   // scroll down for new item
                    **$(".sc-cart-item-list").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");**
```